# Figure out logical function from a CMOS logic circuit

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, function

"Given that Vdd > 0, determine the logical function that this CMOS circuit represents."
Any help on how to approach this problem would be great.
Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: I may have expressed myself the wrong way. I am asking for help on how to APPROACH this problem.
I am not asking for anyone to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the T3/T4 structure, with regard to input B ... Work out what that does, then consider how T1/T2 must work with regard to input A ... Once you have an understanding of those subsections, figuring out how T5/T6 come into the equation should be easy.

Comment: Thank you! If you could link me to a guide about this/cite a book with these kind of problems it'd be awesome. So far I haven't been able to find any information on how these  circuit-to-logical-function problems have to be solved.

Comment: T3/T4 is a logical inversor, pretty easy. T1/T2 depend on A but they also depend on B because B determines whether T5 is on/off and thus determines the source of T1. Your answer really didn't help at all. I have been searching for quite a bit on the web and books but can't find anything that helps me solve this kind of problem.